# Showing classes in scatter plot inside groupplot environment

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

It's possible to the following plot inside a group in groupplots?

[image]

So far I was able to do this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{example_data.dat}
    total_bill tip sex
    16.99 1.01 Female
    10.34 1.66 Male
    21.01 3.50 Male
    23.68 3.31 Male
    24.59 3.61 Female
    25.29 4.71 Male
    8.77 2.00 Male
    26.88 3.12 Male
    15.04 1.96 Male
    14.78 3.23 Female
    10.27 1.71 Male
    35.26 5.00 Female
    15.42 1.57 Male
    18.43 3.00 Female
    14.83 3.02 Male
    21.58 3.92 Female
    10.33 1.67 Female
    16.29 3.71 Male
    16.97 3.50 Female
    20.65 3.35 Male
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group size=1 by 2,
                    vertical sep=2pt,
                },
                grid=both,
            ]

                \nextgroupplot[
                    xticklabel=\empty,
                    yticklabel=\empty,
                ]

                \nextgroupplot[xlabel=Total bill, ylabel=Tip, yticklabel pos=left,]
                \addplot[
                    scatter,
                    only marks,
                    mark size=2,
                ]
                table[x=total_bill, y=tip, meta=sex]{example_data.dat};
            \end{groupplot}

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

The code for the first plot is

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{example_data.dat}
    total_bill tip sex
    16.99 1.01 Female
    10.34 1.66 Male
    21.01 3.50 Male
    23.68 3.31 Male
    24.59 3.61 Female
    25.29 4.71 Male
    8.77 2.00 Male
    26.88 3.12 Male
    15.04 1.96 Male
    14.78 3.23 Female
    10.27 1.71 Male
    35.26 5.00 Female
    15.42 1.57 Male
    18.43 3.00 Female
    14.83 3.02 Male
    21.58 3.92 Female
    10.33 1.67 Female
    16.29 3.71 Male
    16.97 3.50 Female
    20.65 3.35 Male
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.8\linewidth,
            height=6cm,
            xlabel={Total bill},
            ylabel={Tip},
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            xmin=0, xmax=60,
            ymin=0, ymax=10,
            scatter/classes={
                Female={mark=square*,red},
                Male={mark=triangle*,blue}
            },
            legend entries={Female,Male},
            legend pos=north east,
        ]
            \addplot[scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic]
            table[x=total_bill, y=tip, meta=sex]{example_data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to split up the plot into two, so that the first shows the values for `male` and the second for `female`?

Comment: @JasperHabicht no, I want to show the groups in the lower plot, I try to create an axis, but, because is inside an `groupplot` env, it didn't work. My ultimate goal is to make an aproximation of the `jointplot` from Seaborn Python package

Comment: Thanks @Mensch ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea whether this is what you want, but maybe you want to use a filter to split the plot into two, so that the first shows only the values for `Male` and the second for `Female`. If this is not what you want, the below code should at least show you how to position two plots that are styled as the one you showed inside a `groupplot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{filecontents*}{example_data.dat}
    total_bill tip sex
    16.99 1.01 Female
    10.34 1.66 Male
    21.01 3.50 Male
    23.68 3.31 Male
    24.59 3.61 Female
    25.29 4.71 Male
    8.77 2.00 Male
    26.88 3.12 Male
    15.04 1.96 Male
    14.78 3.23 Female
    10.27 1.71 Male
    35.26 5.00 Female
    15.42 1.57 Male
    18.43 3.00 Female
    14.83 3.02 Male
    21.58 3.92 Female
    10.33 1.67 Female
    16.29 3.71 Male
    16.97 3.50 Female
    20.65 3.35 Male
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread{example_data.dat}{\datatable}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\pgfplotsset{
    filter~explicit/.style~args={#1~is~#2~in~#3}{
        x~filter/.code={
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{#1}\of#3
            \str_if_eq:NNF \pgfplotsretval { #2 } {
                \tl_clear:N \pgfmathresult
            }
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group size=1 by 2,
                    vertical sep=4em,
                },
                grid=both,
                width=0.8\linewidth,
                height=6cm,
                axis x line=bottom,
                axis y line=left,
                xmin=0, xmax=60,
                ymin=0, ymax=10,
                scatter/classes={
                    Female={mark=square*, red},
                    Male={mark=triangle*, blue}
                },
            ]

            \nextgroupplot[xlabel=Total bill, ylabel=Tip, yticklabel pos=left]
            \addplot[
                scatter,
                only marks,
                mark size=2,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                filter explicit={sex is Female in \datatable}
            ]
            table[x=total_bill, y=tip, meta=sex] \datatable;
            \legend{Female,}
            
            \nextgroupplot[xlabel=Total bill, ylabel=Tip, yticklabel pos=left]
            \addplot[
                scatter,
                only marks,
                mark size=2,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                filter explicit={sex is Male in \datatable}
            ]
            table[x=total_bill, y=tip, meta=sex] \datatable;
            \legend{,Male}
            
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Was as simple as add `scatter/classes` as a `groupplot` parameter hum, thanks, it did help me a lot!